# Static/sticky Header Using Dynamic Table

Tags: html, css, html-table, dynamic-tables, tableheader

Please can someone guide me on how to implement a static (sticky) header to this dynamically created table?

I have tried multiple things from Stackoverflow threads for a while now but lack HTML/CSS knowledge and I'm obviously missing something simple.

I have managed to get it working using a table created directly in the main body of the code, but when I use my dynamically created tables from JSON I can't get anything to 'stick'.

Below the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.50, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
<head>

    <title>iNews HTML Running Order</title>
    <style>
        table 
        {
            border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            text-align: left;
            font:30px Arial;
        }
        tr, th, td
        {
            white-space: nowrap;
            padding-right: 50px;
        }
        tr
        {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
        }
        th
        {
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
        }
        #container
        {
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="initialisePage('LW')">

    <p id="showData">Loading Running Order...</p>


</body>


<script>
    var loop;
    var filename;
    var table;

    function updateJSONData(filename)
    {
        getDataFromJSON(filename)
        loop = setInterval(function(){getDataFromJSON(filename);}, 500);
    }

    function initialisePage(newFilename)
    {
        filename = newFilename;
        updateJSONData(filename)
    }

    function setFileName(newFilename)
    {
        clearInterval(loop)
        filename = newFilename;
        updateJSONData(filename)
    }

    function getDataFromJSON(filename)
    {
        $.get( "http://10.142.32.72/dashboard/"+filename+".json", function( data ) {
            var myBooks = JSON.parse(data);
            CreateTableFromJSON(myBooks)
        });
    }

    function CreateTableFromJSON(myBooks)
    {
        var title = ["Page", "Slug", "Pres 1", "Pres 2", "CAM", "Format", "Clip Dur", "Total", "Backtime"];
        var col = ["page-number", "title", "pres1", "pres2", "camera", "format", "runs-time", "total-time", "back-time"];

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = title[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            if (myBooks[i]["floated"] == "true"){
                tr.style.color = "#ffffff";
                tr.style.background = "blue";
            }

            if ((myBooks[i]["break"] == "true") && (myBooks[i]["floated"] == "false")){
                tr.style.background = "#00ff00";
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
        console.log("Refreshed: " + filename);
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Many thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: Your `<table>` should have separate `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements instead of using the single implicit `<tbody>`. You don't need to do `divContainer.innerHTML = ""` because it's created empty already. Finally, to make it sticky use `table > thead > tr > th { position: sticky; }` (this does require you to use `<thead>`, of course).

Comment: I thought they were separate elements because I use .createElement for each?

Please can you explain whereabouts I should put <thead> exactly?

Comment: If you don't know where `<thead>` goes I think you should read more about HTML's table structure before continuing. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead

Comment: I've been reading up on this but it's not clicking with me. I'm so close to the last part of the project - please could you point me as to how to separate it into the two elements? I've been staring at the screen for so long now nothing makes sense. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove `<body onload="initialisePage('LW')">` and use `DOMContentLoaded` instead as it happens much sooner than the document `load` event.

  - [`load` is only fired after ALL resources/content has been loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event), including "non-essential" (non-DOM) content like images and external content like ad-banners, which means the `load` event may be fired tens-of-seconds after [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) which makes the `load` event kinda useless today).
- Change your CSS to this:

  ```
  table > thead > tr > th {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 10;
  }

  table > tbody > tr.floated {
      color: '#ffffff';
      background-color: 'blue';
  }

  table > tbody > tr.broken {
      background-color: '#00ff00';
  }
  ```
- JavaScript uses `camelCase` for functions, values (variables and parameters) and properties, not `PascalCase`.
- Avoid `var` and use `const` and `let` in scripts where appropriate instead. Note that `const` means "unchanging reference" (kinda like C++); it does *not* mean "immutable" or "compile-time constant value". I think this definition of `const` was a mistake by the JavaScript language designers, but that's just, like, my opinion, man.
- Use CSS classes via `classList` instead of setting individual style properties using `.style`.
- The current JavaScript ecosystem also generally uses [1TBS instead of the Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).
- Prefer `===` (exactly-equals) instead of `==` (equals) because JavaScript's *type coercion* can be surprising).
- Avoid using `innerHTML` wherever possible. Use `.textContent` for setting normal text content (and avoid using `.innerText` too). Misuse of `innerHTML` leads to XSS vulnerabilities.
- It's 2020. STOP USING JQUERY!!!!!!!!!!

  - [Cite](https://love2dev.com/blog/jquery-obsolete/)
  - [Cite](https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/why-not/)
  - [Cite](http://vanilla-js.com/)
  - [Cite](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)
- DONT USE ALL-CAPS IN YOUR JAVASCRIPT COMMENTS BECAUSE IT LOOKS LIKE THE AUTHOR IS SHOUTING AT YOU NEEDLESSLY AND IT GETS QUITE ANNOYING FOR OTHER READERS ARRRRGGGHHHHH
- You need to handle HTTP request responses correctly (e.g. to check for succesful responses with the correct `Content-Type`).
- Avoid using `j` as an iterable variable name because it's too visually similar to `i`.
- Change your JavaScript to this:

  ```
  <script>
  // You should put all of your own application-specific top-level page script variables in their own object so you can easily access them separately from the global `window` object.
  const myPageState = {
      loop    : null,
      fileName: null,
      table   : null
  };
  window.myPageState = myPageState; // In the top-level function, `const` and `let`, unlike `var`, do not create a global property - so you need to explicitly set a property like so: `window.{propertyName} = ...`.

  window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', onDOMLoaded );

  function onDOMLoaded( ev ) {

      window.myPageState.fileName = "LW";
      window.myPageState.loop = setInterval( refreshTable, 500 );
  }

  async function refreshTable() {

      if( typeof window.myPageState.fileName !== 'string' || window.myPageState.fileName.length === 0 ) return;

      const url = "http://10.142.32.72/dashboard/" + window.myPageState.fileName + ".json";

      const resp = await fetch( url );
      if( resp.status === 200 && resp.headers['ContentType'] === 'application/json' ) {
          const deserialized = await resp.json();
          ceateAndPopulateTableFromJSONResponse( deserialized );
      }
      else {
          // Error: unexpected response.
          // TODO: error handling
          // e.g. `console.error` or `throw new Error( "Unexpected response." )`, etc.
      }
  }

  function ceateAndPopulateTableFromJSONResponse( myBooks ) {

      // TODO: Verify the `myBooks` object layout (i.e. schema-verify `myBooks`).

      const columnTitles = ["Page", "Slug", "Pres 1", "Pres 2", "CAM", "Format", "Clip Dur", "Total", "Backtime"];
      const columnNames = ["page-number", "title", "pres1", "pres2", "camera", "format", "runs-time", "total-time", "back-time"];

      const table = window.myPageState.table || document.createElement( 'table' );
      if( window.myPageState.table !== table ) {
          window.myPageState = table;
          document.getElementById("showData").appendChild( table );
      }

      // Create the <thead>, if nnecessary:
      if( table.tHead === null )
      {
          table.tHead = document.createElement( 'thead' );

          const tHeadTR = table.tHead.insertRow(-1);
          for( let i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++ ) {
              const th = document.createElement('th');
              th.textContent = columnTitles[i];
              tHeadTR.appendChild( th );
          }
      }

      // Clear any existing tbody:
      while( table.tBodies.length > 0 ) {
          table.removeChild( table.tBodies[0] );
      }

      // Populate a new <tbody>:
      {
          const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

          for( let i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++ ) {

              const tr = table.insertRow(-1);
              tr.classList.toggle( 'floated', myBooks[i]["floated"] === "true" );
              tr.classList.toggle( 'broken' , myBooks[i]["break"  ] === "true" && myBooks[i]["floated"] === "false" );

              for( let c = 0; c < columnNames.length; c++ ) {
                  const td = tr.insertCell(-1);
                  const colName = columnNames[c];
                  td.textContent = myBooks[i][ colName ];
              }
          }

          table.appendChild( tbody );
      }

      console.log( "Refreshed: " + window.myPageState.fileName );
  }
  </script>
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this. I've learnt a lot from your explanation - it still requires some work but it's in a much better shape.

Comment: WAS LOOKING AT THE SOLUTION PROVIDED. USED THE SUGGESTED CSS IN MY EXISTING TEMPLATE BUT IT ISN'T WORKING?? HOWEVER THE BULLET POINTS ARE AN EYE OPENER...

Comment: @carla caps-lock plz

Comment: YEAH... DID U THINK OF AN ALTERNATIVE??

Comment: @carla Turn off your caps-lock first.

Comment: BEEN TRYIN, BUT - NO STICKY.